# How to indent a bullet list that spans more than one line

Tags: android, bulletedlist, text-indent

I am able to create a bullet span in android. This is the snapshot of what I have achieved

[image]

How can I indent to ensure that a list item that spans more than one line does not start at the same point with the bullet as shown in this snapshot?

[image]

This is my code

```
String description="";
        for (JsonElement e:sl.get("description").getAsJsonArray()){

            if(!e.getAsString().trim().isEmpty() && CharMatcher.javaUpperCase().or(CharMatcher.javaLetter().negate()).matchesAllOf(e.getAsString().trim())) {
                SpannableString s1 = new SpannableString(e.getAsString());
                s1.setSpan(new BulletSpan(20), 1, e.getAsString().length(), 0);
                description +=s1 + "\n\n";
            }else if(!e.getAsString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    SpannableString s1 = new SpannableString(e.getAsString());
                s1.setSpan(new BulletSpan(20), 1, e.getAsString().length(), 0);

                description += "\u25CF " +"  "+ s1 + "\n\n";
            }
        }

        viewHolder.body.setText(description);
        viewHolder.body.setTypeface(tf);
```

This is the xml

```
<me.biubiubiu.justifytext.library.JustifyTextView
            android:id="@+id/body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement a `LeadingMarginSpan` prior to setting the `BulletSpan`:

```
s1.setSpan(new LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(30, 60), 1, s1.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
```